# 'NoneType' error using Python SSHTunnelForwarder

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, ssh-tunnel

Im trying to put together a script that will run on a scheduled basis, updating a database located on the cloud. im using SSHTunnelForwarding to establish a connection with my database. its all packed within a function so that all i have to do is pass the query string within the function and it runs. this function is looping over about 1000 rows of data within a CSV. each row is being altered to the proper format and a sql expression is being created.

```
with open (CSV, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = next(reader)
    #load new data
    for newrow in reader:
        row = []
        for val in newrow:
            try:
                val = float(val)
            except:
                val = "'"+val.strip()+"'"
            row.append(val)

        id = row[0]
        phase_order = row[1]
        Ajera_Project_Key = row[2]
        project_id = row[3]
        Project_Description = row[4]
        Ajera_Client_Key = row[5]
        Client = row[6]
        Ajera_PM_Key = row[7]
        Project_Manager = row[8]
        Ajera_PIC_Key = row[9]
        Principal_In_Charge = row[10]
        title = row[11]
        Ajera_Dept_Key = row[12]
        Project_Status = row[13]
        Phase_Status = row[14]
        Department = row[15]
        Project_Type = row[16]
        start = row[17]
        end = row[18]
        hours_budgeted = row[19]
        Hours_Worked = row[20]
        Hours_Remaining = row[21]
        Total_Contract_Amount = row[22]
        Billed = row[23]
        Billed_Labor = row[24]
        Billed_Hours = row[25]
        WIP = row[26]
        Spent = row[27]
        Spent_Labor = row[28]
        FTEs = row[29]

        q = 'INSERT INTO project_phases_test VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12},{13},{14},{15},{16},{17},{18},{19},{20},{21},{22},{23},{24},{25},{26},{27},{28},{29});'.format(id,phase_order,Ajera_Project_Key,project_id,Project_Description,Ajera_Client_Key,Client,Ajera_PM_Key,Project_Manager,Ajera_PIC_Key,Principal_In_Charge,title,Ajera_Dept_Key,Project_Status,Phase_Status,Department,Project_Type,start,end,hours_budgeted,Hours_Worked,Hours_Remaining,Total_Contract_Amount,Billed,Billed_Labor,Billed_Hours,WIP,Spent,Spent_Labor,FTEs)

        print (q)

        query(q)
```

the issue im having is when i try to enter a query string other than a simple select. every insert, update, delete statement i pass to it, i get an error that says 'NoneType' object is not iterable. however, as i mentioned before, if i pass a select statement, i get the result im looking for and i dont get any errors.

here is the function

```
def query(q):
    try:
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
          (host, 22),
          ssh_username=ssh_username,
          ssh_password=ssh_password,
          ssh_private_key=ssh_private_key,
          remote_bind_address=(localhost, 3306)
        ) as server:
          conn = db.connect(host=localhost,
          port=server.local_bind_port,
          user=user,
          passwd=password,
          db=database)
          pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)
          conn.close()
        return
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        pass
```

the error is coming from the print e statement.

full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MAMP\htdocs\WIGHTcloud\dataLoader\load\loader.py", line 183, in <module>
    query(drop) # drop phases table
  File "C:\MAMP\htdocs\WIGHTcloud\dataLoader\load\loader.py", line 140, in query
    pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 431, in read_sql_query
    parse_dates=parse_dates, chunksize=chunksize)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1600, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you show the full trace?

Comment: @Xilpex edited original to show full error message

Answer (score 1):

using what nilleb said, i plugged it into the sshTunnelForwarder and got it working.

```
with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(ssh_address_or_host = ssh_host,
        ssh_username = ssh_username,
        ssh_password = ssh_password,
        ssh_pkey = ssh_pkey,
        remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306),
    ) as tunnel:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
          host=localhost,
          user=sql_username,
          passwd=sql_password,
          database=db_name,
          port=tunnel.local_bind_port
        )
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        val = ("John", "Highway 21")
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is expected. An instruction like SELECT will produce an output, including the table headers.

While other DDL statements do not produce an output and thus raise an exception in the pd.read_sql_query function.

You should rather consider retrieving a cursor, and executing the DDL statement on it, like

```py
mycursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("John", "Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @wmunsell please, could you mark this as the answer to your question?